# How to implement a shared secret version of NimbusJwtDecoder and NimbusJwtEncoder

Tags: java, jwt, nimbus-jose-jwt

I’m trying to implement a solution with the encoder/decoder from the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt` package with a **shared secret**.
But my attempt fails when I try to encode a token with a `JwtEncodingException`.
I have asked this question in another form, but here I include a simple ready to execute example, to verify the problem.

```
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableSecret;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.*;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EncoderDecoderTest {
  public static String secret = "j8IoV1jF67";

  public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() throws JOSEException {
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "AES");
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> immutableSecret = new ImmutableSecret<SecurityContext>(originalKey);
    return new NimbusJwtEncoder(immutableSecret);
  }
  public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "AES");
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(originalKey).build();
    return jwtDecoder;
  }

  public void tester() throws JOSEException {
    JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
            .issuer("self")  //Only this for simplicity
            .build();
    var encoder = jwtEncoder();
    //This line throws the exception
    String token = encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    System.out.println(token);

    var decoder = jwtDecoder();
    Jwt jwt = decoder.decode(token);
    System.out.println(jwt.getIssuer());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JOSEException {
    new EncoderDecoderTest().tester();
  }
}
```

jps has come up with a an explanation to why this doesn't work (AES is not a valid signature algorithm), thanks :-)
I guess my question could then be rephrased into: how do I implement a shared secret version of these two encoders/decoders, for example with HMAC using SHA-256?

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder
org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder
```

I tried (a lot) but have not yet succeeded ;-(
Any suggestions for how to fix this problem?

Comment: I guess it's because of the AES key. AES is not a [valid signature algorithm](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-3.1) in JWT.

Comment: Yes, that seems like a sensible explanation - thanks. The reason why I went this way was an example taken from chapter 15 in the book “Spring Security in Action” where the decoder is implemented as in my example. This book does not present an (synchronous) example with the org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder since the token was generated by a separate authentication server.
I have update my question to reflect your input

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the input from jps (AES is actually OK for encrypted tokens, but not signed) and Github Copilot I came up with a working solution using HMAC-SHA256:

```
//Don't hardcode like this for real
  public static String secret = "s/4KMb61LOrMYYAn4rfaQYSgr+le5SMrsMzKw8G6bXc=";

  public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() throws JOSEException {
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> immutableSecret = new ImmutableSecret<SecurityContext>(key);
    return new NimbusJwtEncoder(immutableSecret);
  }

  public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(originalKey).build();
    return jwtDecoder;
  }

  public void tester() throws JOSEException {
    //Create the TOKEN
    JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
            .issuer("https://somewhere.com")  //Only this for simplicity
            .build();
    var encoder = jwtEncoder();
    JwsHeader jwsHeader = JwsHeader.with(() -> "HS256").build();
    String token = encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(jwsHeader, claims)).getTokenValue();
    //Decode the TOKEN
    var decoder = jwtDecoder();
    Jwt jwt = decoder.decode(token);
    System.out.println(jwt.getIssuer());
  }
```